# Find images that fits the best container size

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function that find the best fit image by its his size to his container.

- The image width and height should not be over the container size in any dimesion.
- The image that returned should be the on with the least empty space `min(space)`.

I tried some naive approach using javascript but Im not sure its efficient or elegant solution.

```
let arr = [{'id': 1, 'width': 10, 'height': 10},
{'id': 2, 'width': 20, 'height': 20},
{'id': 3, 'width': 30, 'height': 30},
{'id': 4, 'width': 40, 'height': 40},
{'id': 5, 'width': 50, 'height': 50}]

let height = 25
let width = 25

let best_min_height_delta = Infinity
let best_min_width_delta = Infinity
let best_empty_space = Infinity
let selected_id = -1

arr.forEach(element => {

  if (height >= element.height && width >= element.width) {

      let delta_height = height - element.height
      let delta_width = width - element.width 

      if (delta_height < best_min_height_delta && delta_width < best_min_width_delta) {
      
        let empty_space = delta_width + delta_width
        
        if (empty_space < best_empty_space) {
                    best_min_width_delta = delta_width
                  best_min_height_delta = delta_height
                  best_empty_space = empty_space
                  selected_id = element.id
        }
        
      }
  }
  
})

console.log('the winner is: ' + selected_id)
```

Comment: Why are you setting both `best_min_width_delta` and `height` with the `delta_width` value?

Comment: Right! thats a bug, Im fixing now

Comment: also you might want emptyspace to be `delta_width + delta_height` instead of width.. I think this is pretty straightforward and good approach, but it wont return any image if no image matches

Comment: What do you mean by best fit? Is it the image that leaves the smallest area of white space altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a rectangular box, empty space will then be the area of the inner box subtracted from the area bounding box. So in your code:

```js
let empty_space = (width * height) - (element.width * element.height);
```

Also note, right now you are `empty_space` as `delta_width + delta_width` which seems wrong.